# How to handle $x_{ij}x_{ji}=0$

Tags: discrete-optimization, operations-research

Given a complete bi-directional graph $G=(V,\overrightarrow{E})$, let's consider the following formulation:

$$\begin{align} min \quad & \sum_{k\in {V}} \Big(\alpha_{k}-\sum_{(j,k) \in \overrightarrow{E}} x_{jk}\alpha_{j}\Big)^2 + \sum_{(j,k) \in \overrightarrow{E}} c^T g \\ & x_{ij} \leq M g_{ij} \quad (i,j) \in \overrightarrow{E} \\ & \psi_{ij}+ \psi_{ji}=1 \quad (i,j) \in \overrightarrow{E} \\ & g_{ij} \leq \psi_{ij} \quad (i,j) \in \overrightarrow{E} \\ & A \psi \leq t \\ & g_{ij}, \psi_{ij} \in \{0,1\} \quad (i,j) \in \overrightarrow{E}\\ & x_{ij} \geq 0 \quad (i,j) \in \overrightarrow{E}\end{align}$$

This is a Mix-Integer Quadratic Optimization which can be solved by opt solvers (e.g., Gurobi). That said, this formulation has poor relaxation because of big-M constraint.

Alternative formulation: Since we have $\psi_{ij} + \psi_{ji}=1$, it is clear that we have a disjuction constraint in the form of $x_{ij} x_{ji}=0$.

What would be an effective way to deal with this disjuction constraint. In the same spirit, can the decision variable $x_{ij}$ be tighten with other inequalities?

My first attemt is to add this inequality: $x_{ij}x_{ji} \leq g_{ij}^2$ to tighten the range for $x_{ij}$ but it makes the problem non-linear (cannot be solved by Gurobi anymore).

Edit: There is no natural way to identify a tight big-M for this formulation. What I do is to remove all constraints and optimzie the convex quadratic objective function (without g). Let $x_{ij}^{\star}$ be the solution to this problem. Then, we set $M= 5\times max_{i,j}(x^\star_{ij})$. The exact way to identigy M is both very difficult to solve and also gives way too big M.

Comment: You know $xy=0$? Is that a typo? Also, if $z$ is binary then $z^2=z$, does that help?

Comment: xy=0 is not a typo. I used that trick ($z^2<=z$) to tighten the constraint. I want to tighten the bound for x and y. I am currently using big_M for restricting x and y, and the performance is not satisfying. Just to give a bit background, x and y are the direction (weight) of an arc in a graph. One of them at most should exist (graph is acyclic).

Comment: If $xy=0$ then isn’t the constraint just equivalent to $z \ge 0$?

Comment: I need to clarify that I don't  have xy=0 explicitly in my formulation. I have a constraint like x <= M g where g is binary and y <=M(1-g). It seems to me that the constraint xy <=z^2 is stronger than z>=0 because x and y can take strictly positive value in the continuous *relaxation*. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes you are. Can you reformulate the question ?

Comment: It would help if you write out the whole optimization problem (or the key parts of it). And please make clear which constraints are *actually* part of the problem and which constraints are *optional* but you are thinking about adding them because you think they will tighten the formulation, or for some other reason.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610, thanks for your comment. I provided more detail information. I appreciate any thoughts/comments.

Comment: How do you choose the value of M?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610, Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: OK darn, I was hoping for some low hanging fruit there. :) Unfortunately nothing comes to mind as far as strengthening the formulation. If anything does, I will post. However, the question is now clearer and hopefully someone more expert than I can chime in.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Yes, I think the question is clearer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give a definite answer without more insight into the problem, but a few thoughts come to mind.

1. If the $A$ matrix is nonnegative, then $Ag\le A\psi$, in which case I think you can eliminate $\psi$ from the formulation (and replace $\psi_{ij} + \psi_{ji} = $ with $g_{ij} + g_{ji} \le 1$.
2. Larry asked about how you compute $M$. You may already be doing this, but I would suggest that $M$ be $M_{ij}$. There's no need to use the same value of $M$ in every constraint. If you can provide *a priori* upper bounds $M_{ij}$ for each $x_{ij}$ (the tighter the better), your current formulation might perform better.
3. Assuming neither of the above helps enough, you might try a version of Benders decomposition (with no guarantee that it will help). You could replace the first term of the objective with a variable $z\ge 0$ and remove the $x$ variables and the big-$M$ constraints from the master problem. In a subproblem, invoked when the solver thinks it has a solution to the master, you minimize the quadratic expression subject to $x_{ij}\le 0$ for all $(i,j)\in S=\{(m,n) : g^*_{mn} = 0\}$, where $g^*$ comes from the hypothetical master solution. Let's say that minimum of the subproblem objective comes out $\hat{z}$. The constraint $z\ge \hat{z}\left(1-\sum_{(i,j)\in S} g_{ij}\right)$ is then valid in the master problem. How weak it is would be an empirical question. It might also be possible to shrink $S$ a bit in the new constraint, by eliminating terms for which the KKT multiplier of the corresponding constraint $x_{ij}\le 0$ in the subproblem had the wrong sign (meaning that letting $x_{ij}$ take a positive value would not help $\hat{z}$) ... if in fact that every happened.

Comment: Thanks so much. 1) Yes, the matrix A has negative elements.  2) Unfortunately, it seems that it's hard to make M dependent on (i,j). 3) This looks very promising approach mainly because we can impose those x_{ij} <=0 constraint in the sub-problem. I worked the details and I think I followed the approach. My only question is about the valid inequality in the master problem (the part you sum over S). S seems to depend on g^{*} obtained in the master problem itself. So, I'm not sure about set S in this valid inequality. I would appreciate further clarification about this inequality.

Comment: I guess I understood it. That said, I think this inequality is also valid: $z>= \hat{z} (1-\sum_{(i,j) \in S} g_{ij} - \sum_{(i,j) \in S'} (1-g_{ij})$ where $s' = \{(m,n): g^{*}_{mn} =1\}$. Please let me know if I'm missing something here. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, your inequality is also valid, and is the more generally used one, but is weaker than the one I proposed. In this particular case, "switching off" one of the $g_{ij}$ that was "on" in the candidate solution can only hurt the value of $z$, not help it. So I'm pretty sure my inequality is valid.